# Chain Links remain raised (i.e. sticky link)

Tags: chain, derailleur

I was trying to adjust my rear derailleur but I heard a noise. I found that when the chain went through the pulleys one link of the chain stayed up and made a noise.

How do I fix this?

[image: photo of the chain]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chain is "pinched" such that the friction in this one joint is greater than the force applied by the chain toward straight.

The effects are a periodic "clonk" as this goes through the rear derailleur approximately every 2-3 crank rotations and it stops when you coast.

The roadside fix is to put your thumbs on the sticky rivet, grab the chain either side with fingers of both hands, and flex it sideways.  Use about as much force as it takes to open a screw-bottlecap.  You're not trying to fold the chain.

Then, the link should go flat, in line with the rest of the chain.  If it doesn't try a little more back-and-forth force.

You can also use a chain tool in the "half" position, to "push" that one pin/rivet in a tiny amount.

---

If the chain is approaching its end of life, you may be better off to consider chain replacement soon.

However, I've personally had a chain do this, and then got a couple thousand km more out of it.

Answer (score 5):

Your chain has seized.  It may be possible to work that out, but it's an indication that the chain is likely needing replacement.

To work it out, you'll first need to try to clean it (using an appropriate cleaner) and then lubricate it.  You may need penetrating oil before applying chain lube; the goal is to work it until it loosens.  It's possible it may need to be re-cleaned before lubricating it.

If you're going to clean that link, it's a good time to clean the chain as a whole.

If that fails (and there's a good likelihood it will) or you don't want to muck around with cleaners, then you can shorten the chain with a chain tool.  I'm not a good judge, but if that's an old enough chain you might be able to reuse the existing pins; otherwise you'll need replacement pins or a quicklink.  Shortening the chain will affect the gears you can reach; you probably won't be able to use your lowest gear afterward.

Most likely, however, and this would actually be my "step 1" is simply to replace the chain.  It avoids messing with solvents or buying a chain tool for a quick-fix that may not work and won't last anyway.

Comment: Also, possibly the OP can loosen the link as in step 4 in [this link](https://www.bikeradar.com/features/how-to-fix-a-stiff-chain-link/). However, that presumes that the chain isn't too worn, and I agree you do need to lube the chain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily because the chain is dirty or worn. [If the side plates are bent](https://baartgroup.com/roller-chain-clinging-to-sprockets/) the link does not articulate well. I had this on a new bicycle.

You need to replace the bent link. How much this can be done without replacing the whole chain, see other answers.